# Html select on focus no longer shows default browser styles how to put them back?

Tags: html, css

I have this select element which I have placed the following styles:

```
  select {
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
  }
```

Now when its focused it no longer displays browsers default focus, I know I can use pseudoclass :focus to put custom styles, but I just want for it to have browsers default style, how to achieve this?

Comment: when you specify your own style you override the default browser one and you can no more get them back unless you redifine them again

Comment: Maybe you simply want to use `select:not(:focus)` ...?

Answer (score 1):

In most browsers this is normal behavior. When outline/border is defined, most browsers ignore the user-agent stylesheet and the default focus ring isn't shown.

You can use browser-specific CSS proprieties like `-webkit-focus-ring` (chrome) to make them reappear.

Comment: is that the attribute or the value?

Comment: It's a CSS propriety. (Not value)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I can't, I'm using Firefox. But take a look at google about browser-specifc CSS.